# Pycharm Referenced Error With Import Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

Am using Python 3.6.5rcs , pip version 9.0.1 , selenium 3.11.0. The Python is installed in C:\Python and selenium is in C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\selenium. The environment variables have been set. 
But the code
     **from selenium import webdriver**
gives an unresolved reference error.
Any suggestion on how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pycharm > Preferences > Project Interpreter

Then hit the '+' to install the package to your project path.

Or you can add that path to your PYTHONPATH environment variable in your project.

Answer (score 2):

I found this worked for me. I'm using PyCharm Community 2018.1.4 on Windows.

Navigate to: File->Settings->Project: [project name] -> Project Interpreter

On this page click the configuration wheel at the top which should provide a drop down menu. Click "Add" and a window should appear called "Add Python Interpreter"

You will be defaulted onto "Virtualenv Environment" tab.

There should be a checkbox called "Inherit global site-packages". Check this.

Click OK.

All your installed packages should be added.

Answer (score 1):

I used this command to resolve my error:

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Install selenium and webdriver-manager from the option "python package" directly in the pycharm solve my problem

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to import "By" with:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

It helped me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If `selenium.webdriver` isn't  found, how can `selenium.webdriver.common.by` exist?